# Windows: How to programatically connect to wireless networks?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, network-programming, netsh

With Windows 10 is it possible to setup up known networks and be able to connect to them without all the mouse movement and click?

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows batch files, you can set it up to connect to networks you already know (Network1 or Network2, below) without ever touching the mouse.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in ("Network1"
            "Network2") do (
    netsh wlan show networks mode=ssid | findstr /C:%%i
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        echo "Found %%~i - connecting..."
        netsh wlan connect name=%%i
        exit /b 
    ) else (
        echo "Did not find %%~i"
    )
)
@echo on
```

Save the above to .bat and run it from cmd.exe or a program like Listary.

Some comments about the code:

1. If more than one of your listed networks are available, it will connect to whichever is first in the for loop list. You could also put the list in a file and change `for %%i` to `for /F %%i`
2. `EnableDelayedExpansion` and "!" around `ERRORLEVEL`
   are needed to keep the variable `ERRORLEVEL` from being assigned
   whatever it was at the beginning of the script. Since I don't
   normally program Windows batch files, this is 2 hours of my life
   gone that you won't have to deal with.
3. All the echoing is for debugging; the echo off at the top squelches it.
4. `%%` needed for variables in Windows batch files. The variable is referenced with `%` at the command line.
5. `%%~i` strips the quotation marks around the string when outputting to stdout.

Comment: You know I can pretty much find about a half dozen question and answers on StackOverFlow that address this topic.

Comment: @Squashman - Got a link? I looked and couldn't find anything that tied it together, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.